# Query over initialisation of global variables

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Not able to figure out why this code gives error.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
unsigned long long A[102];
A[0]=2;
int main()
{
    cout<<"OK";
}
```

Error while compiling:

```
prog.cpp:6:1: error: ‘A’ does not name a type
```

But this works fine.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
unsigned long long A[102];
int main()
{
    A[0]=2;
    cout<<"OK";
}
```

What could be the reason ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
A[0]=2;
```

is not an initialization, it is an assignment to the first element of `A`. You cannot do that outside of a function.

This is initialization, and is legal:

```
#include<iostream>

unsigned long long A[102] = {2};

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"OK\n";
}
```

It will set the first element to `2` and all the rest to `0`.